How to prove the strong T transversality for Reed-Muller [[15,1,3]] code?
I don't know how to prove the strong T transversality for Reed-Muller [[15,1,3]] code?
Is there a simple way to figure it out by writing the stabilizer generators?

The key feature is that all the $X$ stabilizers have a weight that is $0\text{ mod }8$ (actually, exactly 8 in this case) while the logical $X$ operator flips every qubit.
What's going on here? The code is CSS, so the stabilizers are either $X$-type or $Z$-type. Let the set $G$ be the set of $X$-type stabilisers. You can write the logical 0 state as
$$
|0_L\rangle=\sum_{g\in G}g|000000000000000\rangle,
$$
so each basis state has weight 8. If you apply a phase gate $T$ on every qubit, then 7 of them get a phase 1, while 8 get a phase $e^{i\pi/4}$. The total phase is 1. Thus,
$$
T^{\otimes 15}|0_L\rangle=|0_L\rangle.
$$
On the other hand,
$$
|1_L\rangle=X^{\otimes 15}|0_L\rangle,
$$
which means that every basis state has 7 1s and 8 0s. Hence, if we apply $T^{\otimes 15}$, on each basis state we gain a phase $e^{i7\pi/4}=e^{-i\pi/4}$. Hence
$$
T^{\otimes 15}|1_L\rangle=e^{-i\pi/4}|1_L\rangle.
$$
The logical action of $T$ applied to every physical qubit is $T^\dagger$.
